# Generate Web Service Skeleton (Server Side artifacts) using wsimport

Tags: java, web, wsdl, jax-ws, wsimport

I have written a wsdl file and trying to generate server side artifacts to provide the actual business logic.

but I am failed to generate server side artifacts

I am using the below command

**wsimport -keep -d  Employee.wsdl**

Its not generating the service class with business method(Operation). It looks its generating the client artifacts instead server .

Can anybody help me to solve this?

Comment: This may help: [using-wsimport-command-generate-web-service-client](http://www.thejavageek.com/2015/01/28/using-wsimport-command-generate-web-service-client/).

Comment: Hey TIm, Thanks for the reply... but the one you posted shows how to generate client stub... I am looking for server skeleton class

Comment: It seems you should use command `wsimport -keep Employee.wsdl`, as written In the article suggested above.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue. It looks like wsimport tool generates both client and service stub. The service interface class gets the name of "portType" in wsdl file:

```
<wsdl:portType name="XPortType">
```

Then in generated XPortType.java you can see web service annotation:

```
@WebService(name = "XPortType" ...
public interface XPortType {
```

You can create your service implementation class as follows:

```
public class XServiceImpl implements XPortType
```